# requests/urllib libraries not returning entire page

Tags: python, json, get, python-requests, urllib

I am attempting to retrieve a very large json document from a web page. When I directly use GET from the terminal I can retrieve the entire document. However if I use requests or urllib I am unable to retrieve it (even when trying to use chunks). Instead the string just gets truncated randomly after about 90,000 characters.  How do I get around this?

```
rstring = ''
req = urllib2.Request('page_with_json')

r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
with open('file_name', 'wb') as f:
    chunk = True
    while chunk:
        chunk = r.read(1024)
        rstring += chunk
    r.close()
```

`rstring` truncates at a random location

error:

```
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1474387 (char 1474386)
```

(because it was truncated)

Comment: You can try `requests` for fetching data. `rstring = requests.get(url)`.

Comment: I've already tried both. Same result.

Comment: Have you tried `json.load`?: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: ....   simplejson.load fails exactly the same, except with an actual error message. The root cause is an invalid json due to truncating due to those libraries not returning the entire response.